# Contemporary Design and One-to-One Relationships: code-first vs data-base first approaches

Tags: design, architecture, database, database-design, single-responsibility

After reading, [Does it ever make sense NOT to condense one to one relationships?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/328820/218080), I wanted to take the question further with regards to contemporary design of entities, front-end code and controllers. The top answer is great, but one thing not addressed is how a code-first approach and modern websites may, if at all, impact our database design decisions.

Imagine a page that contains data on an a **job applicant**. Instead of one giant form of 50 fields. The modern approach may include using a SPA framework where a component contains individual components responsible for each of the following sections (each containing their own specific details):

1. Contact Info
2. Social Media Links
3. Location
4. Current Employment
5. Education
6. Standardized Tests
7. Diversity

Let's take **Social Media Links**. This subsection could include links to a **Job Applicant**'s Instagram, LinkedIn, and more -- and for sake of simplicity, let's ignore that the fields can often be NULL, let's assume these are always a one-to-one relationship, and that there are only four fields (for now). I feel like the **database-first** developer, in good textbook fashion, would say,

> "Put all these fields into the `JobApplicant` table."

Which I normally would have agreed with. Having now adopted more code-first approaches and gained more experience with designing front-ends into components/modules, moving away from single form-wide POSTS/PUTS has caused me to view `SocialMedia` as being an entity, both in the front-end and back-end. I then take that further and consider - if the user changes only a SINGLE field on this page, like `LinkedInUrl`, do I want to send a CRUD operation to a `JobApplicantController` to update a `JobApplicant` entity or would I rather notice the state change (React, Angular, etc.) happening in the `SocialMedia` component and consequentially send this to a `SocialMediaLinksController` on clicking save? Additionally, if changes to this applicant are made elsewhere by a different user in real-time, do I want to update state on the page via `JobApplicantController` with a bloated looking ViewModel or would I rather have individual controllers that update their own associate state?

For me, it's increasingly become the later of these questions. I also find that new comers to the project have an easier time onboarding when the UI components, which closely represent a business presentation, match more similarly with the database, instead of having so many one-to-one columns shoved into a God-like entity.

But should we ignore this and adhere to the database textbooks? One-to-one relationships should be represented as a single column in a single table?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  This is all academic speculation if you're not solving an actual problem.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The problem Im trying to solve is that I have database-first developers who want every single one-to-one relationship to be in a parent table, whereas I have code-first developers who want to make the tables more modularized to closely match the entities they're working with on both the server and front-end components, and not rely heavily on growing Gob-objects and ViewModels.

Comment: It sounds like your code-first developers expect the database to bend to their will, i.e. evolve based on their class designs.  In large systems (of non-trivial size), that's generally not how this works; developers must adhere to some API or database schema that has been designed by someone else.  So it's hard for me to be sympathetic to their point of view, especially when the Adapter Pattern exists.

Comment: In other words, if they don't need all of the fields in Job Applicant, they can simply craft a DTO that only has the fields they do need.

Comment: You should design the DB model the way it takes the most of the DB features and  design the software's domain data model, the way it's more efficient in memory. Put a layer of indirection in between. Both teams are wrong if they think it must be only one or another.

Comment: @RobertHarvey "code-first developers expect the database to bend to their will, i.e. evolve based on their class designs" Doesn't this happen either way? If we need to add a new Social Media Link field, say StackExchange, you either add a column to JobApplicant or a column to SocialMedia - either way, the database is going to "bend" so I dont see you what you're trying to communicate there :(

Comment: As I understand it, Code First generates database models from the classes, correct?  This only works in the most isolated of cases... for example, where you're working with a microservice that is the sole owner of the data, maintained by a small team of developers.  If that is the case, then sure, they can architect that database however they want, and present that data to the external world through an API of their choosing.  But once people start using that API, its design becomes "frozen;" you can't change it without breaking everyone else's clients.

Comment: So at the end of the day, yes, it is a database design, and yes, you can evolve it through the class design, but if you allow that, the Code First developers better own that database in its entirety.  Once others start using that database directly, it doesn't belong to the Code First developers anymore.

Comment: And yes, I know I'm not answering your database design question directly, so here's the direct answer: in my experience, the only time a 1:1 relationship justified is when the joined table records are *optional.*  [This answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/328823/1204) agrees with me, and describes a few other scenarios where 1:1 relationships might be useful.

Comment: In short, you don't compromise your database design just because some developers like working a certain way.  You wouldn't discard database normalization to make life easier for the Code First folks, would you?

Comment: See also [here](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/25123/one-to-one-relationship): *"A one-to-one relationship in a relational database occurs when one parent record or field has either **zero or one child record only."***

Comment: @RobertHarvey I feel like all of your points are great and fit exactly into this the question on this post. Your sense of "database-first" means the developers who work with the DB now have to bend the program's architecture to the will of the DB. You seem to feel the code-first approach bend's the db architecture. Thats the whole point of my question.

Comment: Speaking as a code first developer myself, I must admit that everything Robert has said here is correct. But it’s what Laiv said that lets me live happily anyway in the world of Robert being correct.

Answer (score 0):

### What should come first?

Opposing code-first and database-first assumes that one must necessarily drive the other.
This idea is not modern: it is prehistoric.  It ignores the evolution of software engineering in the last 40 years from [sequential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waterfall_model) to [iterative and incremental](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Process) and [agile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agile_software_development) approaches.

Code and database are two side of the same coin (or 2 faces of the same dice):

- The code is implemented around an object model, a part of which represents domain objects that matter to the users.
- The database implements a model that consist mostly of domain objects.

They are at their best when synergies between the two **complementary viewpoints** are exploited, rather than imposing a monolithic view, or having to rely on (and maintain) a suboptimal mapping.

### Shall the database be designed based on the user-interface?

There are a couple of misconception on database design in your question. For example:

> I feel like the database-first developer, in good textbook fashion, would say, "*Put all these fields into the JobApplicant table.*"

Really? Any database serious designer would first try to understand how the fields relate to each-other before deciding on the design of tables and relations (or the documents or the graphs in case of NoSQL).  Exactly as a code-first developper would first try to understand how the page would look like and component content should relate to each other.  Again, two sides of the same coin.

The idea of user interface driving the database design seems not so popular nowadays. It may work well in smaller projects.  But it's definitively not a modern practice.  The past 50 years of programming and software engineering are based on the discovery of the [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller):

- Before MVC, models (be it in code or in database) were tightly intermixed with the user-interface. It was very difficult to maintain.
- But since [Trygve Reenskaug](http://Trygve%20M.%20H.%20Reenskaug) and [Adele Goldberg](http://Adele%20Goldberg) 's discovery, we all know that [many views and controllers can share the same model](https://folk.universitetetioslo.no/trygver/themes/mvc/mvc-index.html). And all the subsequent MV* architectures are based on a similar decoupling of the model (i.e. in the code and the database) from the user-interface itself.

Answer (score 0):

> Let's take Social Media Links. This subsection could include links to a Job Applicant's Instagram, LinkedIn, and more -- and for sake of simplicity, let's ignore that the fields can often be NULL...

This is actually the part you should pay attention to. If they can be null, then they are optional. The other problem I see is naming these fields after the social media company. Remember MySpace? That was a social media company too. Imagine this was 20 years ago, and you put a MySpace column on the job applicant table. Now fast-forward to today. Would any row in the job applicant table have a value for this column? Worse yet, would you have put Facebook URLs in the MySpace column, because you thought it was silly to add a Facebook column?

Whether thinking about this code-first or database-first, it is modeled wrong. Social media should be an entity, but I would also recommend creating a SocialMediaType table, where you can add a record for each social media company you want to store links for. Now you can deprecate the MySpace URL and add any new companies that are out there.

> ... I feel like the database-first developer, in good textbook fashion, would say,
>
> > "Put all these fields into the JobApplicant table."

I highly doubt someone familiar with database design and normalisation would think this. Social media is not just a separate entity, it is a separate *table* as well. This is not a one-to-one relationship. It is one-to-many. This perfectly captures the optional nature of social media links. If one is not provided, no row will exist for that job applicant and social media type.

> ... if the user changes only a SINGLE field on this page, like LinkedInUrl, do I want to send a CRUD operation to a JobApplicantController to update a JobApplicant entity or would I rather notice the state change (React, Angular, etc.) happening in the SocialMedia component and consequentially send this to a SocialMediaLinksController on clicking save?

The data model you choose should not drive how and when you choose to save data. This should be driven by the desired user interaction and usability. You can aggregate multiple updates to the JobApplicant entity, or send individual INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statements to the database. SQL and a good Object-Relational Mapper can give you the flexibility to choose either strategy.

The real challenge is understanding how to properly model the data, and recognize abstractions in data as well as behavior. Whether you think about the code or database first is irrelevant. You do eventually need to think of both, and you need to be familiar with best practices and concepts from both areas.

Comment: Social Medias into its own table is great. Especially when having a SocialMediaTypes table; can see how it’s much more flexible. Let’s say there’s a SocialMediaType for Facebook, and in the record table of Candidates who have SocialMedia profiles, we’d have a row in the SocialMedia table for their linked Facebook account. Let’s say you want to store data specific to Facebook that isn’t specific to all SocialMedia. Let’s say - FBMessengerEnabled. Do you put a bool column in SocialMedia? Getting gurenteed nulls almost everywhere, like a MySpace record, except for Facebook rows?

Comment: @8protons: it is difficult to judge where to put something like FBMessengerEnabled, unless we know more about the problem being solved. It also depends on whether or not you can identify an abstraction that applies to multiple social media services. Facebook isn't the only service with instant messaging capabilities. It just happens to be called "Facebook Messenger".